# How to show injection and surjection elementry set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $f:\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)\to\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)\\ \forall x\in\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R) \ f(x)=X\cap\Bbb N
>   $
>
> Check whether $f$ is an injection and a surjection over $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R) $.

For the surjection what I did was:

Let $z\in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R) \\ \exists x\in\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R) \Rightarrow f(x)=z \\x=z\cap\Bbb N \\ f(x)=f(z\cap\Bbb N)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$

So it isn't a surjection.

For the injection, we need to show that:

$x,y\in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R) \\f(x)=f(y) \\ x\cap \Bbb N=y\cap \Bbb N \\ \emptyset = \emptyset$

Now I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here but I don't know what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's $f(\mathbb{N})$ and $f(\mathbb{N}\cup\{-1\})$?

Comment: Both will give you $\Bbb N$. Does that mean it is an injection ?

Comment: This means it's not an injection (as there exists $X,Y$ with $X\neq Y$ but $f(X)=f(Y)$. This contradicts the definition of injective function.